# How to create adhoc network on Raspberry pi ZERO W?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi-zero, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to make adhoc network connect mobile phone and other pc devices to Raspiberry pi zero w

- Device :: Raspiberry pi Zero W
- Release :: 10
- Codename :: buster

I followed below steps to try to make adhoc nw on my Raspiberry pi zero w

```
cd /etc/network 
sudo cp interfaces interfaces.backup 
sudo nano adhoc-interface
```

added below in my adhoc-interface file

```
auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  iface eth0 inet dhcp

  auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 4
  wireless-essid RPitest
  wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

Installed dhcp

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Added below to my dhcpd.conf

```
  ddns-update-style interim;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  authoritative;
  log-facility local7;
  subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.2.5 192.168.2.150;

  }
```

Added my wlan0 interface to

```
sudo /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

as below

```
INTERFACESv4="wlan0"
```

After all above on reboot, my device is able to get 192.168.2.1 ip , but its not visible on other mobile and computer devices.

**Anybody can help,what am i missing more ?**

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, follow as below answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to do that , i followed as below

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome openvpn openvpn-systemd-resolved network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome -y 
sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5 -y 
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

After above i got an icon in taskbar to create a hotspot to which I was able to connect other devices.